# Firefly has its own gravitational field?

Tags: firefly, artificial-gravity

In Firefly episode eight, *Out of Gas*, the engine breaks, causing the oxygen and heating to go offline on Serenity. For some reason, the gravity stays on. Mal (the captain) is able to move about freely, clearly drawn to the ground. Items are not floating about. The backup engine was not working, as stated by Kaylee (the engineer) when asked about extra time for oxygen.

Is there a rare metal in the Firefly universe that, when no longer near a gravitational pull, emits its own? Or some kind of gravity field that is not created by a piece of machinery that is required to be on? Is this ever addressed?

Comment: This Q seems more about how the gravity works **when the power is out** as opposed to how it works in general. Maybe not a duplicate?

Comment: @MeatTrademark The linked question asks about "Out of Gas", and the accepted answer deals primarily with a junked ship with no (or limited) power

Comment: @JasonBaker The ship is not junked, nor does it have limited power. The ship in "Out of Gas" is Serenity from Firefly, and is fully operational with the exception of a broken part. In the episode the engine broke, as did the backup generator (meaning no power whatsoever).

Comment: @XosMel I was talking about the ship in the short story "What Holds Us Down", which is referenced in the accepted answer to the linked question. The state of that ship and *Serenity* may not be exactly the same, but it's similar enough